# IntelliJ IDEA Community edition, Indentation does not go back 4 places at a time, it only goes 1 space

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation, jetbrains-ide

Working with IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition -
When I type enter after {} brackets the cursor move to a new line and auto-indent occurs, BUT, when I press the left arrow key the indent should go back but, that does not happen and it goes back only 1 space, This problem was not there earlier, but now it is not working.

Please tell a solution for this problem or a plugin that can solve this problem

Comment: You may have had Tabs instead of Spaces before. Pressing `Left Arrow` key will move caret for 1 symbol (be it a Space or a Tab), but for Tab it visually will look like 4 symbols (or whatever the Tab size you have got there).

Comment: Try pressing `Ctrl+Left Arrow` instead. It should take you back to the previous line.

Comment: But only left arrow worked for me earlier, then I enabled soft wrap and after that it is not working, I have also tried by restoring the default settings but still that doesn't work.

Comment: Well I got the solution by enabling the (Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Language | Use tab character) and then reformatting the whole file.